# [python - get the list of keys in a list of dictionary]

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries
input:

```
x = [{'id': 19, 'number': 123, 'count': 1}, 
     {'id': 1, 'number': 23, 'count': 7}, 
     {'id': 2, 'number': 238, 'count': 17},
     {'id': 1, 'number': 9, 'count': 1}]
```

How would I get the list of number:

```
[123, 23, 238, 9]
```

Thank you for you reading

Comment: Try:  `[i['number'] for i in x]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get these numbers you can use

```
>>> [ d['number'] for d in x ]
```

But this is not the "list of keys" for which you ask in the question title.
The list of keys of each dictionary d in x is obtained as `d.keys()`
which would yield something like ['id', 'number', ...]. Do for example

```
>>> [ list(d.keys()) for d in x ]
```

to see. If they are all equal you are probably only interested in the first of these lists. You can get it as

```
>>> list( x[0].keys() )
```

Note also that the "elements" of a dictionary are actually the ***keys*** rather than the ***values***. So you will also get the list ['id', 'number',...] if you write

```
>>> [ key for key in x[0] ]
```

or simply (and better):

```
>>> list( x[0] )
```

To get the first element is more tricky when `x` is not a `list` but a `set` or `dict`. In that case you can use `next(x.__iter__())`.

**P.S.:** You should actually think what you really want the keys to be -- *a priori* that should be the 'id's, not the 'number's, but your 'id's have duplicates which is contradictory to the concept and very definition / meaning of 'id' -- and then use the chosen keys as identifiers to index the elements of your collection 'x'. So if the keys are the 'number's, you should have a *dictionary* (rather than a list)

```
x = {123: {'id': 19, 'count': 1}, 23: {'id': 1, 'count': 7}, ...}
```

(where I additionally assumed that the numbers are indeed integers [which is more efficient] rather than strings, but that's up to you).
Then you can also do, *e.g.*, `x[123]['count'] += 1` to increment the 'count' of entry `123`.

Comment: there is no need for `.keys()` ... also, `[ key for key in x[0] ]` should just not be there, **anything** of the form `[x for x in whatever]` should just be `list(whatever)`

Comment: That's exactly what I explain in my answer! The keys() attribute is there for a reason -- it is (obviously, by definition) the "official" way to get the keys, so I mention it, but then I proceed by showing that iterating over the "elements" of a dict actually iterates over the keys (which is counter-intuitive for unexperienced programmers, they consider keys as indices and iterating over elements of a container shouldn't run over indices but over values) -- and finally I say that this is obtained by `list ( [the dict] )`.

Comment: PS: if you re-read my answer, it was also to demonstrate that the actual keys are not the "keys" the OP asked for in the question (title). If I just write `list( x[0] )` this does not show or "prove" that the result is indeed the **keys** of the dict, therefore I first wrote `[ list( d.keys()) for d in x]` to make it obvious and beyond any doubt, what the keys of the elements of his list of dicts (?!) are.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
numbers = [dictionary.get('number') for dictionary in list_of_dictionaries]
```

Comment: You can also do ```dictionary['number']``` in place of ```dictionary.get('number')```

Answer (score 1):

Using a functional programming approach:

```
from operator import itemgetter

x_k = list(map(itemgetter('number'), x))
#[123, 23, 238, 9]
```